# The resource is not on the build path of a java project (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

Also whenever I try to see the methods of a DS using the "." the IDE won't show me the methods of the map. It's like if I'm programming in a word document, no help of the IDE. Also you can see the weird colors of the variables in the photo. I don't know what's happening.

[image: [alert screenshot]]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the syntax coloring, but when working with Java, at minimum you need some context: the relevant "classpath". Eclipse provides that by having you create a Java Project and setting up the project's Java Build Path. The error message is telling you that it can't do what you're trying to do because you lack all of that. Without that information, there's no way to tell if you're referring to types, methods, and fields that actually exist, and definitely nothing against which to create completion proposals.

So create a project using the New Java Project wizard. Put your source file into the Source Folder, in the correct place according to its package statement, and then proceed with whatever it is you were trying to do.